# Adding an element to an xdocument at runtime vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0, linq-to-xml, .net-4.5

I have two programs,

one is a webservice written in C# .NET V4.5 and the other is written in VB.NET V4.0

I am using the xDocument class to create an xml document to send to a webservice,

in the VB program i have this code:

```
 Dim xdoc As New XDocument(
         New XElement("Submission",
            New XElement("Enquiry",
               New XElement("customerurn", dms.data("Enquiry", 3)),
               New XElement("enquiryurn", dms.data("Enquiry", 4)),
               New XElement("salestype", sType),
               New XElement("ispartofmulitpurchase", "N"),
               New XElement("contactsource", "1"),
               New XElement("contactmethod", Cmethod),
               New XElement("mediasource", "OTH"),
               New XElement("ModelOfInterest",
                  New XElement("Vehicle",
                     New XElement("isnewvehicle", newUsed),
                     New XElement("description", dms.data("Enquiry", 10) & " " & dms.data("Enquiry", 11) & " " & dms.data("Enquiry", 16)),
                     New XElement("manu", dms.data("Enquiry", 10)),
                     New XElement("model", model),
                     New XElement("isavailable", "1")
                     )
                  ),
                  New XElement("disabled", "0"),
                  New XElement("status", status),
                  New XElement("haspx", hasPx),
                  New XElement("Statistics",
                     New XElement("updated", CurrentTimeStampAdf()),
                     New XElement("updatedby", getNRCAStaffNo(staffNo))
                     )
                  )
               )
            )
```

which works fine,

however i now at runtime need to add another element if there is a part ex vehicle present,

The problem is when i use the code which i use in the C# .NET 4.5 project

```
xDoc.Descendants("Enquiry").Last().Add
```

The extension methods (.Last, .firstordefault) etc do not exist, is this correct and they are specific to .NET 4.5 onwards or am i missing something?

if these methods are .NET 4.5 + only is there an alternative i can use?

Comment: Are you asking if there are .Last(), .FirstorDefault(), etc.. extension methods are available in .NET 4.0 for XDocument.Descendants ?

Comment: I assume that you have included:
Import System.Linq  right?

Comment: yes i have included system.xml.linq and system.linq

Comment: edit: sorry double checked and i was missing the imports statement for System.Linq... DOH,

Comment: i had System.Xml.Linq but not System.Linq, Thanks

Comment: Please mark as an answer if it solved your problem and you can also upvote if the given solution is nice and neat! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you included:

```
Import System.Linq
```

Also if you try to get a specific element, you can use:

```
var q= from c in xmlFile.Descendants("Enquiry") select c;
```